# Can we run OctopusDeploy step in team city in parallel

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy

I have a build process in team city which creates 3 packages from the same code base. Then I deploy them to 3 different apps as 3 different octopus deploy steps.

Right now they deploy one after another. I wanted to check if these 3 steps can be executed in parallel. I don't get any options to do so though.

Answer (score 0):

## Run steps in parallel

Source: https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/run-steps-in-parallel